# how to show a image in fragment over the activity when the image is clicked?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to android, i am using RecyclerView to list the images without using third party libraries. It works perfectly but when I click the image, i need to show the image in fragment over the activity.

when `onClick` method trigger, call interface method `ItemClickListener`

```
   @Override
   public void ItemClickListener(View view, int position,Bitmap bitmap) {


   ActivityFragment frag=new ActivityFragment();
   Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
   ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   bundle.putParcelable("bitmap", bitmap);
   Log.d("fff", String.valueOf(bundle));
   frag.setArguments(bundle);

   FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
   FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
   transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
   transaction.add(R.id.linearLayoutRecyclerView, frag, "bitmappassing");
   transaction.addToBackStack("bitmappassing");
   transaction.commit();


}
```

This is ActivityFragment.java

```
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View layout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity, container, false);
//   Bitmap args=getArguments().getParcelable("bitmap");
   Bitmap bitmap=getArguments().getParcelable("bitmap");
    Log.d("fff","fragment"+bitmap);
    imageView= (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.id_fragmentImageView);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


    return layout;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use dialog with custom layout.

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ActivityName.this.getLayoutInflater();
        View imageDialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_image, null);
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(imageDialog);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

        ImageView imgImage = (ImageView) imageDialog.findViewById(R.id.imgImage);
            // Set your image 

        dialog.show();
   }
});
```